# 'Translate' .sh to .bat

Tags: scripting, batch-file

HI!
I would like to use this simple script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=$1
echo $filename | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g';
```

In a script.bat, but my computer is not Windows, so I can't test it. This one would be correct??

```
prueba.bat 

filename=%1  
echo %filename% | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you simply wait till you have a Windows machine and then test it?

Comment: @ghostdog74 How is that comment relevant to anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite:

```
@echo %1| sed "s/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g"
```

But you do have to make sure you have a `sed` available ([CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) are excellent for these tools - I prefer GnuWin32 if you only need specific things, CygWin tends to give you a *lot*).

You also have to be careful with environment variables like `filename`. While UNIX will create them in the context of the current shell (so its effect will be limited), `cmd.exe` scripts will "leak" them (hence the direct use of `%1`).

Comment: Actually, that doesn't make a difference to the CygWin `sed` but I'm not sure about GnuWin32 so I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

In cmd.exe, `%1%` does not mean anything, use `%1` or, better, `%~1` which removes possible quotes around instead.

Also, use double quotes for literal expressions for sed. Single quotes would be passed to sed.

```
 set filename=%~1
 echo.%filename%| sed "s/\([A-Z\)/ \1/g"
```

In bash, use `"` around your `$` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `set` for declaring a variable, and preferably use `@echo off`

```
@echo off
set filename=%1
echo %filename% | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g';
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows cmd.exe hates single quotes

```
echo %filename% | sed "s/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g";
```