# How to get parameter in a .bat file from a java project

Tags: java, batch-file

Yesterday I asked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812821/translate-sh-to-bat), but I am still having problems when I try to run this .bat file from my java project.

```
@echo off
set filename=%1
echo %filename | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g';
```

The call I do is:

```
String param = "myparam";  
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myFile.bat", param);
```

But what myFile.bat does is just print `%filename`, so it doesn't take the real value of the param I send.
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

I tried also

```
@echo off
set filename=%1
echo %filename% | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g';
```

With the same result, now it prints `%filename%`.

Maybe some problems in the call??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to execute `cmd.exe /c script.bat` instead, so that cmd.exe (the command shell) will expand variables. In Windows, .bat files are not full fledged executables, just input files for the command processor (`cmd.exe`).

Comment: I get this error in my eclipse console:   

Cannot run program "cmd /c myscript.bat" (in directory "mydirectory"): error=2, No such file or directory.  


But of course, myscript.bat is in that directory

Comment: try splitting up the command in several strings: `("cmd.exe", "/c", "script.bat")`

Answer (score 1):

you missed the second `%`. Should be:

`echo %filename% | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g';`

Comment: are you running the bat file at a windows cmd prompt?

Answer (score 1):

`%filename` is missing a `%` at the end. It should be: `%filename%`